# INSERT rule does not always fire

Tags: postgresql

We have a Postgres 11 server. There is table of `machines` and `history` table which contains the changes within machines table.

There is insert rule on `machines` table:

```
CREATE RULE machine_insert AS ON INSERT TO machines
  DO ALSO
    INSERT INTO history(machine_name, stamp, ...)
      VALUES(new.machine_name, now(), ...);
```

The insert into history works perfectly if the statement looks like this

```
INSERT INTO machines(machine_name, ....)
  SELECT machine_name from new_machines; -- No condition
```

But if there is a JOIN and WHERE condition in the select statement, the rule does not fire at all. e.g.

```
INSERT INTO machines(machine_name, ....)
  SELECT machine_name 
  FROM new_machines N 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN machines D on D.machine_name = N.machine_name
  WHERE D.machine_name is null -- "Anti Join"
```

As I understand the documentation, the select statement in my case above should really have no impact on the rule(s). Remark: simple `WHERE` condition (`WHERE machine_type is not null`) does not disable the rule. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is using a `RULE`. Make your life easier, use a trigger/function and move on.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver. Based on tests we did, the RULEs seem to be much faster. The documentation also hints the performance advantage. We actually replaced Triggers with Rules. Anyhow, I hope someone knows the reason behind the described behavior. Worst case - back to Triggers.

Comment: The answer is in here [Rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules.html), in particular [Rules update](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-update.html). If you can figure what actually happens in all the query rewriting you solve your problem. Performance is good only if the code works and my experience is rules spend a good deal of time not working.

Comment: Thanks for the hints Adrian. Will sure check.

Answer (score 1):

The EXPLAIN ANALYZE revealed the cause of the issue. Here is the output:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Insert on machines  (cost=17.88..14522.89 rows=335609 width=227) (actual time=12586.221..12586.223 rows=0 loops=1)                                          
  ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=17.88..14522.89 rows=335609 width=227) (actual time=0.029..347.021 rows=335959 loops=1)                                        
        Hash Cond: (n.machine_name = d.machine_name)                                                                                                                           
        ->  Seq Scan on new_machines n  (cost=0.00..8588.59 rows=335959 width=105) (actual time=0.013..59.920 rows=335959 loops=1)                    
        ->  Hash  (cost=13.50..13.50 rows=350 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)                                                           
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB                                                                                                 
              ->  Seq Scan on machines d  (cost=0.00..13.50 rows=350 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)                                     
Planning Time: 1.497 ms                                                                                                                                    
Execution Time: 12586.289 ms                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                           
Insert on history  (cost=0.84..30581.85 rows=121724 width=1493) (actual time=212.911..212.912 rows=0 loops=1)                                              
  ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=0.84..30581.85 rows=121724 width=1493) (actual time=212.909..212.909 rows=0 loops=1)                                          
        Merge Cond: (n.machine_name = d.machine_name)                                                                                                                          
        ->  Index Scan using new_machines_idx on new_machines n  (cost=0.42..12138.50 rows=335959 width=15) (actual time=0.005..72.153
        ->  Index Only Scan using machines_id_key on machines d  (cost=0.42..11274.51 rows=214235 width=4) (actual time=0.005..81.540 rows=335959 loops=1)   
              Heap Fetches: 335959                                                                                                                         
Planning Time: 0.264 ms                                                                                                                                    
Execution Time: 212.975 ms
```

The rule does fire (gets executed) and it does work as designed.
The query resulting from the RULE (see `Insert on history` above) really tries to add records to history, but under the `WHERE` condition that the record must not exist in `machines` table which is now FALSE for all records as `INSERT into machines` already went through, note `Scan using machines_id_key ... rows=335959`.